# Date and time wrong on Highstock chart

Tags: php, highcharts

I have had a look at my chart issue and I think the problem lies in the Highstock code. I have 2 other charts running the same php code and I have only changed from highchart to highstock.
I am trying to add a range selector in my chart. The code for that works in terms of showing the zoom and selector buttons but the date is now showing incorrectly.
I am drawing the data from an online MySQL data base so I its hard to run a demo for you.The timestamp format has worked in my other charts as mentioned.

This first code shows the date correctly

```
<?php
// 1-test.php

$servername = "localhost";

$dbname = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, value1, reading_time FROM Sensor order by reading_time desc limit 40";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $sensor_data[] = $data;
}

$readings_time = array_column($sensor_data, 'reading_time');

$i = 0;
foreach ($readings_time as $reading){
    $readings_time[$i] = date("d-M H:i", strtotime("$reading + 16 hours"));
  $i += 1;
}

$value1 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value1')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$reading_time = json_encode(array_reverse($readings_time), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

/*echo $value1;
echo $reading_time;*/

$result->free();
$conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      min-width: 310px;
        max-width: 1500px;
        height: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    h2 {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
  </style>
  <body>
    <h2>Test page 2</h2>
    <div id="chart-temperature" class="container"></div>
    
</div>

<script>

var value1 = <?php echo $value1; ?>;
var reading_time = <?php echo $reading_time; ?>;

var chartT = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: { renderTo : 'chart-temperature',
  type: 'spline'   
  },
  title: { text: 'Roof Temperature' },
  series: [{
  showInLegend: false,
  data: value1
  }],
  plotOptions: {
  spline: { animation: false,
  dataLabels: { enabled: true }
  },
  series: { color: '#059e8a' }
  },
  xAxis: { 
  type: 'datetime',
  categories: reading_time
  },
  yAxis: {
  title: { text: 'Temp (C)' }
    },
  credits: { enabled: false }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then this code shows the date as Thursday,Jan 1, 00:00:00:001

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";

$dbname = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, value1, reading_time FROM Sensor order by reading_time desc limit 40";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $sensor_data[] = $data;
}

$readings_time = array_column($sensor_data, 'reading_time');

$i = 0;
foreach ($readings_time as $reading){
  $readings_time[$i] = date("d-M H:i", strtotime("$reading + 16 hours"));
  $i += 1;
}

$value1 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'value1')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$reading_time = json_encode(array_reverse($readings_time), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

/*echo $value1;
echo $reading_time;*/

$result->free();
$conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  

  <style>
    body {
      min-width: 310px;
        max-width: 1500px;
        height: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    h2 {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
  </style>
  <body>
    <h2>Test Page</h2>
    <div id="chart-temperature" class="container"></div>
    
<script>


var value1 = <?php echo $value1; ?>;
var reading_time = <?php echo $reading_time; ?>;

var chartH = new Highcharts.stockChart({
  chart: { renderTo : 'chart-temperature',
  type: 'spline'   
  },
  title: { text: 'Roof Temperature' },
  series: [{
  showInLegend: false,
  data: value1
  }],
  plotOptions: {
   spline: { animation: false,
  dataLabels: { enabled: true }
  },
  series: { color: '#059e8a' }
  },
          rangeSelector: {

            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 3,
                text: '3d'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: '1w'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 3
        },
  xAxis: { 
  type: 'datetime',
  dateTimeLabelFormats: { second: '%H:%M:%S' },
  categories: reading_time
  },
  yAxis: {
  title: { text: 'Temp (C)' }
    },
  credits: { enabled: false }
});

        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the first screen shot is working. The second is the wrong date,
[image]
[image]
Any thoughts on how to change the date

Comment: What is `number)` after the `foreach` line?

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean? The date and time is called after the 'foreach' line. I am a total newbie so need lots of help

Comment: I'm talking about this in the second snippet: `foreach ($readings_time as $reading){
 number)` It looks like a copy/paste error.

Comment: @Barmar, yes a copy paste error to this forum. I have corrected it

Comment: Hi @james Pattinson, Could you provide me with a sample result of `value1` and `reading_time` variables in JS? Of course from the no-working chart.

Comment: @ppotaczek Hi. value1 is a temp - 18.10 and reading_time is 2021-08-22 15:00:53. Both charts are actually receiving the same data

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the charts results from the fact that the second chart is a stock chart, which doesn't support categories on a x-axis. You need to use data in the `[x, y]` format.

```
var value1 = [18.10, 14.5];
var reading_time = ['2021-08-22 15:00:53', '2021-08-23 15:00:53'];

var seriesData = value1.map(function(val, index) {
    return [new Date(reading_time[index]).getTime(), val];
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xLh7y8d6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

Comment: Thank you for helping. Sorry for the newbie questions. How do I 'use data in the [x, y] format.'   I'm getting the date data from a MySQL database as you can see. Do I need to change that format, and if so how. Or do I format it differently for Highstock.

Comment: Hi @james Pattinson, There is no reason to say sorry. You can prepare the right format in JS, as it is shown in my example above or in SQL query `[x - date in milliseconds, y]`

Comment: Thanks again. I feel a bit useless as this is above my current skill level. Can you help with the code to prepare the right format. You have probably done that but I'm struggling to see where

Comment: It is just the mapping function `value1.map(...)`, an array with two elements is created based on the `value1` array.

Comment: I am getting my data from MySQL. I will end up with 5 values. I have changed my timestamp in MySQL to include milliseconds. The JSON data looks like this 
`{"id":"512","value1":"18.80","value2":"52.80","value3":"-127.00","value4":"-5.0","value5":"100.00","reading_time":"2021-08-24 17:29:32.572"},
{"id":"513","value1":"18.10","value2":"99.90","value3":"-127.00","value4":"-5.2","value5":"100.00","reading_time":"2021-08-24 20:39:05.335"},
{"id":"514","value1":"18.00","value2":"99.90","value3":"85.00","value4":"-5.2","value5":"100.00","reading_time":"2021-08-24 20:39:24.471"}`

Comment: The dates must be in milliseconds, not just include milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. Do I change the date to milliseconds in php or in JS? and how? So Sorry to keep asking newbie questions. I am doing lots of research and not just asking for your help.

Comment: I am not a php expert, but the conversion to milliseconds in JS is here: `new Date(reading_time[index]).getTime()`